# How to unstack a dictionary of dataframe with multiple entries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hi I have this dictionary below

```
str1         x      y
        a   1.0   -3.0
        b   2.0   -2.5 

str2:        x      y                 
        a   3.0   -2.0
        b   4.0   -1.5

str3:        x      y 
        a   5.0   -1.0
        b   6.0   -0.5
```

The result I would like is to be able to unstack it so I get a dataframe with `index=[str1,str2,str3]` and `columns=[a,b]`. To choose whether I use values on columns x or y to fill the row of my expected dataframe, I use the integer N.

You can see N as the limit stating that every row above use x values and below, y values.

`If N=1, I use x values for str 1, y values for str 2 and str 3`.

```
If N=2, I use x values for str 1 and str 2 , y values for str 3.

If N=3, I use x values for str 1, str 2 and str 3.
```

Which will give me for i = 1:

```
        a      b 
str1   1.0    2.0    (x values)
str2  -2.0   -1.5    (y values)
str3  -1.0   -0.5    (y values)
```

I know that I can get two data frames, unstacking on x and y, then concatenating rows that I want to keep but I wanted to know if there were a faster way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code using dictcomp from an Ordered dictionary (a bit more pythonic):

```
def N_unstack(d,N):
    d = collections.OrderedDict(d)
    idx = list('x'*N+'y'*(len(d)-N))
    return pd.DataFrame({k:v[idx[i]] for i,(k,v) in enumerate(d.items())}).T
```

Output for `N_unstack(d,1)` where `d` is the dictionary of dataframes:

```
         a      b
str1     1.0    2.0
str2    -2.0    -1.5
str3    -1.0    -0.5
```

Here is how I would do it (using `pd.concat`). It's a bit verbose:

```
def N_unstack(d,N):
    idx = list('x'*N+'y'*(len(d)-N))
    df = pd.concat([d['str1'][idx[0]],d['str2'][idx[1]],d['str3'][idx[2]]], axis=1).T
    df.index = ['str1','str2','str3']
    return df
```

Edit: made the code a bit more pythonic

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Didn't know it was possible/safe to have the same index on a dataframe. My expected indices were str1 str2 and str3.

Comment: I have altered my function to also modify the index.

Answer (score 0):

To better resolve the question in a Pythonic way, you could first translate your rule (using x or y values) to a dictionary (probably with dictionary comprehension):

```
# replicate the dictionary in the post
>>> d = {'str1':{'a':{'x':1, 'y':-3}, 'b':{'x':2,'y':-2.5}}, 'str2':{'a':{'x':3, 'y':-2}, 'b':{'x':4,'y':-1.5}}, 'str3':{'a':{'x':5, 'y':-1}, 'b':{'x':6,'y':-0.5}}}
>>> indexes = ['str1', 'str2', 'str3']
>>> N_map = {1:{'str1':'x', 'str2':'y', 'str3':'y'}, 2:{'str1':'x', 'str2':'x', 'str3':'y'}}
```

Then we could loop through N=1,... and construct the dataframe with list/dictionary comprehension:

```
# only take the first two rules as an example
>>> for i in range(1, 3):
...   df_d = {col:[d[index][col][N_map[i][index]] for index in indexes] for col in ['a', 'b']}
...   pd.DataFrame(df_d, index=indexes)  

      a    b
str1  1  2.0
str2 -2 -1.5
str3 -1 -0.5
      a    b
str1  1  2.0
str2  3  4.0
str3 -1 -0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

With this dictionary of Dataframes :

```
d2
"""
{'str1':      a    b
         x  1.0  2.0
         y -3.0 -2.5, 
 'str2':      a    b
         x  3.0  4.0
         y -2.0 -1.5, 
 'str3':      a    b
         x  5.0  6.0
         y -1.0 -0.5}
"""
```

Define

```
df2 = pd.concat(d2)
df2.set_index(df2.index.droplevel(1),inplace=True) # remove 'x','y' labels
select = { N:[ 2*i + (i>=N) for i in range(3)] for N in range(1,4) }
```

Then with for example `N = 1`

```
In [3]: df2.iloc[select[N]]
Out[3]: 
        a    b
str1  1.0  2.0
str2 -2.0 -1.5
str3 -1.0 -0.5
```